# Fetching binary value from MSSQL and SELECTing fetched value in python

Tags: python, sql-server, database, escaping, binary-data

I'm required to fetch a value from `TableA` that is represented in `binary(20)`, save this to a variable `sha1_bin`, pass it to another function, which retrieves information from `TableB` using said `sha1_bin`.

When I get the binary value, for instance the first `SHA1` (binary(20)) from `TableA`

```
con.execute_query('SELECT TOP 1 [SHA1] FROM TableA')
for row in con:
    sha1_bin = row['SHA1']
```

it looks like: `b'\xa3\x13\xa4;\xcb\xda\x1b\x1b,Ut\xde\xeb2\xb5\x84\xe5&\x85;'`

finally when I then use this value to retrieve information from `TableB`, for instance some strings..

```
con.execute_query('SELECT [name] FROM TableB WHERE [SHA1] = '+ str(sha1_bin))

for row in con:
    set_of_names.add(row['name'])
```

I get this error:

```
102, b"Incorrect syntax near '\\xa3\\x13\\xa4;\\xcb\\xda\\x1b\\x1b,Ut\\xde\\xeb2\\xb5\\x84\\xe5&\\x85;'.DB-Lib error message 102, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n"
```

From what I understand it's not handled correctly, I assume I need to escape it somehow..

**Question:**
How can I retrieve this `binary(20)` and then use in form of a variable to retrieve correlated data from a second table?

I can't have any database related like joins, the queries need to be kept as they are.

Database: Working on Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition v9.00.3042.00, i.e. SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2

***edit:***

I think I've narrowed down the problem to the initial retrieving of the `binary(20)` value. Because when I assign one of the values in the database to a string variable in the python console (e.g. `0x90D152B5ED57E00336FD8E106A7BCE28FC3EA588`). I have no problem retrieving the information from `TableB`.

How may I retrieve the `SHA1` column which is a `binary(20) from`TableA` in order to use it *properly* in python?

Comment: Maybe because of missing single quotes in where condition

Comment: unfortunately I've already suspected that, but it does not work with single quotes either..

Comment: your query should be like `select ... where [SHA1] = '\\xa3\\x13\\xa4;\\xcb\\xda\\x1b\\x1b,Ut\\xde\\...'`

Comment: I added single quotes, for instance `con.execute_query('SELECT [name] FROM TableB WHERE [SHA1] = \''+ str(sha1_bin)+'\'')`.. I also tried not to cast to `str` but that doesn't work either..

Comment: try this `'SELECT [name] FROM TableB WHERE [SHA1] = ''+ str(sha1_bin)+'''`

Comment: That does not work either, I think in this case the value of the variable is not even used..